# Add wrapper for a CMake find module

Tags: boost, cmake, wrapper

In our project we use boost a lot. So `find_package(Boost ...)` is called often with different components (for different modules/libraries). This causes a lot of `"Imported targets not available"` warnings (like REALLY a lot)

I want to avoid all this log clutter without forcing all users to upgrade CMake when upgrading boost. I can assume newer boost versions are fine. But there is nothing to disable this warning or show it only once.

So my idea was to wrap the `find_package(Boost ...)` and simply return a status. Easiest way seems to create a custom `FindBoost.cmake` and put it in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. But how would I then call into the original boost find-module? If I call `find_package(Boost ...)` again it would probably call the same module again.

Also: Gathering the arguments to pass would probably be quite cumbersome. Is there an automatic way of doing that (like `ARGN` for regular functions)?

Note: The obvious solution of using a custom macro `find_boost` which does this should not be considered as it involves changing all callers.

Comment: "I can assume newer boost versions are fine." - It could be errors about non-meeting dependencies between Boost components, if `FindBoost.cmake` script is older than the Boost version. So ignoring warnings like `Imported targets not available` may lead to unexpected compilation/linking fails.

Comment: We still have to support older boost and CMake versions. So we are using the variables, not the imported targets and manage the dependencies ourselves. Implications of that assumptions have to be handled in some way unrelated to this question.

Comment: `Easiest way seems to create a custom FindBoost.cmake and put it in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. But how would I then call into the original boost find-module?` - Restore `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and call `include(FindBoost.cmake)`. Actually, I don't understand why do you need to chain `FindBoost.cmake`: You may copy original script into "custom" one, and just remove `message(WARNING)` from it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The idea is very good. In fact you can unset `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and restore it after the include. And your 2nd tip is also correct as even the wrapping and setting QUIET does not remove the warning. Can you convert that into an answer so I can accept this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create `FindBoost.cmake` script, which is the same as one in CMake of some version, but with corresponded

```
message(WARNING ...)
```

lines removed.

Add this script into your project, and adjust *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* variable for find it.

---

Boost warnings "Imported targets not available" **cannot** be disabled with *QUIET* option for `find_package`: Shipped with CMake, script `FindBoost.cmake` doesn't check this option when emits these warnings.

Comment: If one **does**  want a wrapper: Simply `unset(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH)`, then `include(FindBoost)`, and reset `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` afterwards.